# Is there any way in angular for freezing screen components while processing ajax save request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am basically saving large data, meanwhile i want to display Saving data... message on screen so that user cannot access any other screen or any button on that screen until save is complete.
An alternate way can also be suggested

Comment: What have you tried? What have you googled?

Comment: @inetphantom i have used angular block ui plugin for it and it is working fine. But issue now i'm  facing is that i want to display gif along with Loading... text .Link for above question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261819/display-loading-gif-in-angular-blockui-plugin

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using an interceptor and a overlay.
An overlay needs to be created as a direct child of body and with following style.

```
#overlay{
   position : fixed;
   left : 100%;
   right : 100%;
   top : 100%;
   bottom : 100%;

   width : 100%;
   height : 100%;

   display : none;
}

#overlay.show{
  display : block;
  z-index : 500000;
}
```

This overlay is not visible by default.

```
app.factory( 'Inteceptor', function($rootScope) {
 int count = 0;
 var overlay = angular.element( document.getElementById( '#overlay' ));
 return {
   request : function() { 
                 if( count == 0 ) {
                    overlay.addClass( 'show' );
                 }
                 count++;
   },
   requestError : function() {},
   reponse : function() {
                  count--; 
                  if( count == 0 ) { 
                         overlay.removeClass( 'show' ); 
                  }
   },
   responseError : function() {}
}});
```

And this is how you push an interceptor in config method.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('Inteceptor');
```

Comment: Bro i have used plugin mentioned in above comment.Btw thanks for your precious time.... Can you help me with problem stated in above comment

Comment: In this solution, you can simply add a gif as the child of overlay.